# Error when using MvxAppCompatActivity

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, appcompatactivity

I am writing an application with Xamarin.Android with MvvmCross. I want my `Activity` to inherit from `MvxAppCompatActivity` so that I can use fragments. Here is my base class:

```
public class BaseActivity<TViewModel> : MvxAppCompatActivity<TViewModel> where TViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public new TViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }
}
```

I get this error on the `OnCreate` of my `Activity`:

> Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$drawable; Didn't
>   find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$drawable" on path:
>   DexPathList...

But if I change `MvxAppCompatActivity` to `MvxActivity` it works fine...why?

Comment: What is your project target version and min version?

Comment: min version is API level 15, and target is API 26 (on the automatic setting to take the latest)

Comment: Would you mind share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo?

Comment: @Darius the sample that you provided, does it produce the error you post after launch? I'm able to launch the app without issue and navigate around. ___Side note___ your `Setup.cs` is inheriting `MvxAndroidSetup` you will need to change that to `MvxAppCompatSetup` (Which uses the `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter`) in order to make use of  compat view types.

Comment: I should also mention I had to change the namespace `xmlns:azzimovmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.azzimov.azzimovmobile"` as I could not get the project to compile.

Comment: Yes the sample that I provided does produce the error after launch when it tries to navigate to the first screen, for me at least...strange...I'm using an emulator with API level 23, what did you test it on? And what did you change the namespace to?

Comment: Hmm, does the project compile fine for you? I had to change to namespace in the `login_screen.xml` to use `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` essentially the same at your local namespace. What version of Android SDK Build and Platform Tools do you have installed?

Comment: Android SDK Platform 23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded your solution and tried to build the Android project. It fails with 18 occurrences of the same error:

`error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'loginButtonBackgroundColor' in package ...`

So after a little inspection of your solution, I did the following steps to solve your issue:

1) In `login_screen.axml` I saw you had this line:

`xmlns:[YOURNAMESPACE]="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[YOUR PACKAGE]"`

Which is unnecessary. After removing it, and changing the lines `[YOURNAMESPACE]:loginButtonBackgroundColor=...` to `local:loginButtonBackgroundColor=...` the build succeeds.

2) I saw some layout files are located inside the `/drawable` folder (`button_round_corner.xml`, `input_box.xml` and `login_button.xml`). I moved them to the `/layout` folder and fixed the issues the change produced (only two).

3) Made `Setup` class inherit from `MvxAppCompatSetup`.

4) Added a `RegisterAttribute` over the `LoginButton` control. So the class definition looks like this:

```
using Android.Runtime;
...

namespace Xxx.Droid.Components
{
    [Register(nameof(LoginButton))]
    public class LoginButton : FrameLayout, IMvxNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And that's it! Probably (2) was not necessary, but leaving it here just in case.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same experience, I was not able to get the error that @Darius described in his question `Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$drawable; Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$drawable" on path: DexPathList.`

Comment: I could reproduce it, I edited my answer @Plac3Hold3r :)

Comment: Nice find for the layout directory issue, did that cause an exception for you when running on an emulator or device and which version? I'm just trying to figure out why it didn't exception for me lol. I was running on v26 emulator.

Comment: Nice! I did all this, including (2), plus delete the obj and bin folders to get it to work. But what does `[Register(nameof(LoginButton))]` do and why is it needed? And why can't I put some layout files in the `drawable` folder? I like to have some separation so that my `layout` folder isn't cluttered

Comment: `RegisterAttribute` is necessary for the Android system to find your custom widget when inflating views, Xamarin registers it to be available through the attribute. I think it's ok if you prefer to keep those files in `drawable/`, but the recommended approach is to keep all of them inside `layout/`. If your app becomes big (100+ screens), both directories will be cluttered, so I wouldn't worry about that

Comment: Done! Can you please accept the answer if it solved your problem? :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be several things but it is probably the lack of some android support packages. Mainly the lack of `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` gives that error. So check if you have that added and if not add it and it should solve your problem.
If it doesn't it's highly likely you lack some other android support packages

Comment: I have `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` ver 26.1.0.1, I tried adding a bunch of support packages with no avail, although it would make sense that I'm missing something

Comment: do you have all of the packages in the same version?

Comment: all the Xamarin.Android.Support.* yes

Comment: that's wierd, have you tried deleting bin and obj folders and rebuilding after that?

Comment: Yes I did try that